# Data not available after neo4j-admin import (Causal Cluster / Neo4J Enterprise Edition)

Tags: database, import, neo4j, cypher, cluster-computing

I am using neo4j-admin import command to import data into a neo4j causal cluster with neo4j enterprise 4.4.7 installed on 9 Ubuntu VMs configured as CORE instances. Cluster is functional and works.
The data I want to import are stored in csv/tbl files generated with tpch-dbgen tool (based on TPCH schema). I have csv files with the headers and tbl files with actual data. The data is generated for scale factor 1 and 10, not so big datasets, but I plan to scale up to 500 if I can make the import work.

I just can't obtain the data after import and I am running into a dead end.
Would really appreciate some guidance !

The steps I take for import:

1. stop neo4j with command /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-4.4.7/bin/neo4j stop;
   I get the message that it's stopping and stopped.
   This step I take on all VMs of the cluster.
2. run the command for import:
   neo4j-admin import --database=tpch --delimiter="|" --ignore-extra-columns=true --nodes=REGION:REGION="/home/ubuntu/tpch_headers/region.csv","/home/ubuntu/tpch-dbgen/data01/region.tbl" --nodes=NATION:NATION="/home/ubuntu/tpch_headers/nation.csv","/home/ubuntu/tpch-dbgen/data01/nation.tbl" --nodes=CUSTOMER:CUSTOMER="/home/ubuntu/tpch_headers/customer.csv","/home/ubuntu/tpch-dbgen/data01/customer.tbl" --nodes=PART:PART="/home/ubuntu/tpch_headers/part.csv","/home/ubuntu/tpch-dbgen/data01/part.tbl" --nodes=SUPPLIER:SUPPLIER="/home/ubuntu/tpch_headers/supplier.csv","/home/ubuntu/tpch-dbgen/data01/supplier.tbl" --nodes=PARTSUPP:PARTSUPP="/home/ubuntu/tpch_headers/partsupp.csv","/home/ubuntu/tpch-dbgen/data01/partsupp.tbl" --nodes=ORDERS:ORDERS="/home/ubuntu/tpch_headers/orders.csv","/home/ubuntu/tpch-dbgen/data01/orders.tbl" --nodes=LINEITEM:LINEITEM="/home/ubuntu/tpch_headers/lineitem.csv","/home/ubuntu/tpch-dbgen/data01/lineitem.tbl";

it displays import completed

3. start neo4j with command /usr/local/neo4j-enterprise-4.4.7/bin/neo4j start;
   I get the message that it started and ran it on all VMs of the cluster.
4. I connect from one of the VMs using cypher-shell to the system database with user neo4j
5. I create the tpch database
6. I select it
7. I run call db.schema.visualization; to see it's data but nothing appears, like it would be empty.
8. I run a simple query like match(n) return count(n); and it displays 0 like no node would be present.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow the steps correctly I think you are loading the database on a single VM of the cluster, is that correct?

If that is the case then the cause could be that when you run the CREATE command a different VM becomes leader for the database, doesn't find any data local to it and creates an empty database which is then synched to the other members (effectively overwriting the actual data you loaded).

In the 4.x series you would need to [seed the database](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.4/clustering/seed/) on all VMs and then run the create database command.

In version 5.x this has been made easier with the [Designated Seeder](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/databases/#cluster-designated-seeder) option allowing you to import on a single member of the cluster and specify that VM in the CREATE database command.

Comment: Add some code or image to support your answer.